# Why only __add_wait_queue(q, wait) when wait is empty?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.5/source/kernel/sched/wait.c#L172

```
void prepare_to_wait(wait_queue_head_t *q, wait_queue_t *wait, int state)
{
    unsigned long flags;

    wait->flags &= ~WQ_FLAG_EXCLUSIVE;
    spin_lock_irqsave(&q->lock, flags);
    if (list_empty(&wait->task_list))
        __add_wait_queue(q, wait);
    set_current_state(state);
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&q->lock, flags);
}
```

In above code, we can see **__add_wait_queue(q, wait)** only executed when **list_empty(&wait->task_list)** is true.

Why when **&wait->task_list** is not empty, then **wait** don't need to be added to q (**wait_queue_head_t**)?

Does that mean if **wait** (wait_queue_t) already in a **q** (wait_queue_head_t ) then don't change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that mean if `wait` (wait_queue_t) already in a `q` (wait_queue_head_t ), then don't change it?

Yes, the branch

```
if (list_empty(&wait->task_list))
    __add_wait_queue(q, wait);
```

means, that `wait` is added to the wait queue `q` only if `wait` hasn't belong to any queue already.

Otherwise, if it is determined that `wait` has already belonged to (some) wait queue, it is assumed that `wait` belongs to `q` specifically, and it is not added again.

---

There is some specific with calling `list_empty` function for an object, which can be a list's **element** (not a head of the list).

`list_empty` always returns **false**, if object belongs to a list.

But if the object doesn't belong to any list, then return value is generally **unspecified** (and in the most cases it is **false** too).

Exception is an object, initialized with `INIT_LIST_HEAD` function or `LIST_HEAD_INIT` macro or deleted from the list with `list_del_init` function: in such cases `list_empty` returns **true** with guarantee.

If look for the usage of `INIT_LIST_HEAD`, `LIST_HEAD_INIT` or `list_del_init` in the `wait.h` header, then it can be found that `prepare_to_wait` function is **allowed** only for `wait` object:

1. Created with `DEFINE_WAIT` macro or one of `DEFINE_WAIT_*` macros.
2. Initialized with `init_wait` function, which is called e.g. from one of `wait_event_*` macros.
3. Which has been passed to `finish_wait` function.

But `prepare_to_wait` function **cannot** be used for a `wait` object, created with `DECLARE_WAITQUEUE` macro: this macro initializes the `task_list` field with `{NULL, NULL}`, so `list_empty` would return false for it (as if the wait object is already added into the wait queue).